# On Vue.js v-model does not keep the value when the user hits the back button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form with checkboxes. When the user marks them as checked I add the value to a vue.js prop.

If the user submits the form and then presses the back button, the boxes checked stay the same but the vue.js variable does not contain the checked values anymore. If I uncheck them and check them again manually then they show up in the variable again.

How can I keep the values in the variable or make the checkboxes unchecked so the user knows that needs to check them again?

HTML

```
{% for entity in entities %}
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedEntities" value='{{ entity.id }}' name="entity_{{ entity.id }}">
<span>{{ entity.name_tag }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Vue.js

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ["${","}"],
    data: {
        checkedEntities: [],
    }
}
```

Note: the entity variable belongs to Django.

Comment: There is a ton of code missing, I can only guess what your code looks like

Comment: Indeed @RobertRocha, I just added all the code related to this functionality. Please let me know if something is still missing.

Answer (score 5):

it's a chrome bug that can be fixed by turning off autocomplete for the radio button:

```
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" v-model="checkedEntities" value='{{ entity.id }}' name="entity_{{ entity.id }}">
```